# How to align a checkBox and an ImageButton horizontally?

Tags: alignment

How do I align checkBox and ImageButton horizontally? I have already tried android:layout_alignBaseline between a TextView and EditText to be ok, but between a checkBox and an ImageButton, the android:layout_alignBaseline attribute don't seem to work as in the following xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:text="@string/termsheading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:text="@string/telephone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView06"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="@string/terms" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:src="@drawable/player_controls_bg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```